# Cannot await in exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

hi im trying to make my discord bot do what im typing im my discord client and i want to use exec() + this is just to test and experiment so it doesnt matter if it may be unsecure.

part of my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('2B: '):
        exec(message.content[4:])   # <--- here is the exec()
    .
    .
    .
```

but this is the error when i type,

```
2B: await client.send_message(message.channel, 'please stay quiet -.-')
```

error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shiyon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shiyon\Desktop\dm_1.py", line 12, in on_message
    exec(message.content[4:])
  File "<string>", line 1
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'please stay quiet -.-')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this may be your problem:

> Be aware that the return and yield statements may not be used outside of function definitions even within the context of code passed to the exec() function

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

This should work better:

```
await eval(input)
```

If you want to be able to use non coroutines too you could check before awaiting the return of the eval.

Here is a snippet from [Rapptz's bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/master/cogs/admin.py#L53) which seems to do something like what you wanted:

````
@commands.command(pass_context=True, hidden=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def debug(self, ctx, *, code : str):
    """Evaluates code."""
    code = code.strip('` ')
    python = '```py\n{}\n```'
    result = None

    env = {
        'bot': self.bot,
        'ctx': ctx,
        'message': ctx.message,
        'server': ctx.message.server,
        'channel': ctx.message.channel,
        'author': ctx.message.author
    }

    env.update(globals())

    try:
        result = eval(code, env)
        if inspect.isawaitable(result):
            result = await result
    except Exception as e:
        await self.bot.say(python.format(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e)))
        return

    await self.bot.say(python.format(result))
````

Explanation edit:

The `await` keyword only works in context because it does some magic with suspending execution in the loop.

The `exec` function always returns `None` and loses the return value of whatever statement it executed. By contrast the `eval` function returns the return value of its statement.

`client.send_message(...)` returns an awaitable object which needs to be awaited in context. By using `await` on the return of the `eval`, we can do this easily and by checking if it's awaitable first we can also execute non coroutines.

Comment: no. in this case the error will change to: `TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression` @Blimmo

Comment: @shiyonsufa you should probably use `eval` rather than `exec`. Since everything in python returns something, it isn't really much different but allows you to deal with the return value for things like await.

Comment: and eval result --> `await client.send_message(message.channel, '... yes, whats the matter?')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @shiyonsufa don't type await when you use the command. Have a read of the explanation I added to the answer if you're still confused. The try block of the snippet is all you really need btw, the rest is for error handling and the like

Comment: wow that's it. `result = eval(message.content[4:])
        await result` @Blimmo